# failed to resolved:com.android.support:design:22.+

Tags: android-studio

I installed android stadio bundle. but when I open it gives me this error
[image]

sdk manager

[image]

Comment: Your Android Support Repository is very outdated. On my machine, I have version 28 for "Android Support Repository". Update to a current version.

Comment: thanks. error was because of space in the path of sdk. I change its path and problem solved!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** Your Project .

**Edit**

Rectify your **SDK Path** please .

Finally

```
dependencies { 
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' 
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: the problem was in path of sdk and changing it, solve the problem. but where should I use this line that you wrote?

Comment: @user3496654 Actually i saw this `failed to resolved:com.android.support:design:22.+` Thats why i told you .Add this in your `build.gradle` section .

Comment: ok, but I want to know you solution too, here should I use this line that you wrote? how can I add that line and where?

Comment: @user3496654 Open your project `build.gradle` and see `dependencies {compile .....`

Comment: I have two build.gradle

Comment: open app `build.gradle` .and see `defaultConfig` quote

Comment: and add this line at the end?

Comment: @user3496654 okay please copy your `build.gradle` in your question section

Comment: @user3496654 Glad to help .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106425/discussion-between-user3496654-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: @user3496654 Please review this answer .

Comment: what happen if i don't include this line in dependencies ?